# Change background login screen in macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, login-screen

I am trying desperately to change the login screen image (defaults to a blurred image) to any other image that I want. I have already tried:

- [How to change your login screen in macOS (and change it back)](http://www.macworld.com/article/3128967/macs/how-to-change-your-login-screen-in-macos-and-change-it-back.html)
- [How to Change the Login Screen Background In macOS Sierra, Yosemite, and El Capitan](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/29503/how-to-change-the-logon-background-in-os-x/)
- [Change login screen in Sierra](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7696404?start=0&tstart=0)

And I can garantee you, none of them work any more in macOS Sierra, they used to in previous versions of the OS, but not anymore.

I would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by editing system .plist's through `defaults` (tedious), or you can use [Onyx](https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html) for this (simple). Onyx is quite a capable utility and it's free - if you like it, donate a bit for the Author though he does a great job with this app.

You can do this by launching Onyx, entering your admin password and choosing the **login** tab:
[image: Onyx login tab]

There are also tons of other options you can check out. Tinkering with **Onyx** is quite secure since you can roll back to defaults with one button press, so don't worry about bricking something - but still be aware what you click ;)

If you want to do this without any extra software, you would need to edit your `defaults` by importing/exporting them. I wrote a script for the exporting part, it writes each `domain` into a separate file for easier overview and keeps system namespace/user namespace separate + sorts out system/apple defaults from those that were changed/set by any software the user installed.

I use it mostly for filtering crap leftovers from tests to keep the defaults tidy- since the background/login is also set there- that's what you need to edit.

In some cases, you might need to parse binary .plist files, and this needs an editor that can parse those- easily done with TextMate (or Xcode if in need of "vanilla"). Hope that solves your problem.

Script is here: [export-defaults.zsh](https://gist.github.com/jankun/6041a6cc9426043bb830f4f4ed658449)

Comment: Thanks but I would rather use a "vanilla" version, I don't want to install any additional software to perform this task, sorry.

Comment: You don't have  to install anything- like I mentioned above- to do this by hand you need to change system defaults accordingly, Onyx does the same for you- hence it's simpler. If you don't know how to work with `defaults` I strongly recommend you use Onyx.

Comment: Depends on your idea of installation - its a binary you can run without installation and delete it after without any leftovers, so there is no installation, it's not a .pkg file. What's your point here?

Comment: Ok, I downloaded Onyx and used it without installing it, I understand now what you meant and it worked, my apologies and thanks again! I am curious though, is really that difficult to override that specific default? Maybe is just a couple commands I'd like to know ;)

Comment: No apology needed, just keep openminded to any answer, you will never know. You can set most of the system stuff through `defaults`, there is plenty of 3rd party apps (Onyx being one) which are a fancy interface/editor to `defaults`, checkout `dotfiles` on github and check the script, you can fiddle inside those files with TextMate. You can basically do almost everything system-wise from the command-line. We could (unjustly) simplify that macOS is a fancy UI that sits on top of Darwin, which is a BSD offshot with Apple "innovations" added.

Comment: Which default key is it?